# Keys and Values re-formatting in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, laravel, laravel-5.1

Please read the whole question before attempting to answer.  If I have two associative arrays where some values match just once:

```
$array1 = ['key1' => 'value1', 'key3' => 'value2', etc...];
$array2 = ['key2' => 'value1', 'key4' => 'value2', etc...];
```

but $array2 is longer than $array 1, and in those cases the keys don't have values:

```
$array1 = ['key1' => 'value1', 'key3' => 'value2'];
$array2 = ['key2' => 'value1', 'key4' => 'value2', 'key5' => 'value3'];
```

Then how can I combine them to get the following result:

```
$array3 = [
'value1' => [$myconstant => key2], 
'value2' => [$myconstant => key4], 
'value3' => [$myconstant => ''],
 etc...];
```

Notice that in cases where there is no match, an empty string is used instead of the key in the embedded associative array.  In fact, the only reason why $array1 is necessary is because I need to know when there is a match with $array2 to get the correct format.

The values will not repeat themselves along the etc... chain.

I'm using Laravel and am trying to use Collections, but basic PHP solutions are okay too.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I really don't see how the two arrays are connected. You just use the value as keys from array2 and the keys as values from array2. If you want to use the key only if the value also exists in array1 and otherwise an empty value, than I kinda see it.

Comment: `$myconstant` can be anything I assume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the biggest hurdle you have is how to transform those values in keys and keys into values. [array_flip](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-flip.php) is the answer to that problem. Once you have that, you can solve your problem with a simple foreach loop.

```
$myconstant = 'foo';
$array1 = ['key1' => 'value1', 'key3' => 'value2'];
$array2 = ['key2' => 'value1', 'key4' => 'value2', 'key5' => 'value3'];

// array_flip switches keys and values in an array
$flip1 = array_flip($array1);
$flip2 = array_flip($array2);

$array3 = [];
foreach($flip2 as $key => $value) {
    if(!isset($flip1[$key])) {
        $array3[ $key ] = [ $myconstant => '' ];
    } else {
        $array3[ $key ] = [ $myconstant => $value ];    
    }

}
```

Laravel Collections have a [flip()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-flip) method, too. That might help you translating the script into Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$array1 = ['key1' => 'value1', 'key3' => 'value2'];
$array2 = ['key2' => 'value1', 'key4' => 'value2', 'key5' => 'value3'];

function x (array $a= array(), array $b = array()) {
    $array = array();
    $index = new ArrayObject($a);
    $seed  = new ArrayObject($b);

    $a_it = $index->getIterator();
    $b_it = $seed->getIterator();

    while ($a_it->valid()) {
        $x = $a_it->current();
        $y = ($b_it->valid()) ? $b_it->current() : NULL;

        if ($y !== NULL) {
            # there is a value to compare against
            if ($x === $y) {
                $array["{$x}"] = array('myConst'=>$a_it->key());
            }
            $b_it->next();
        } else {
            # there is no value to compare against
            $array["{$x}"] = array('myConst'=> '');
        }
        $a_it->next();
    }
    return $array;
} 

$read = x($array2, $array1);
print_r($read);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!